# Laptops with 14" or less screen with good video cards

Tags: laptop, performance, hardware-rec, graphics-card

I'm looking to get a new laptop that's portable and has good graphics performance. What are the best mobile graphics cards around those days and what laptops has them? Battery life time is of less concern for me. I'm going to run Windows Vista 64 bit on it.

Answer (score 4):

Unibody Macbook Pro.

I run Windows 7 on mine and play The Orange Box and good framerates all the time. It can even play The Sims 3 at max settings. WOW!

Comment: I've had trouble getting Windows 7 64bit to work with my pro, are you using the 32bit version?

Comment: You have make sure and get the mid or high end model now to get the dedicated graphics card. The low end 15 inch MBP now uses the same integrated graphics as the macbook.

Comment: 64 bit it is. Updated the question.

Comment: @Troggy I have a 13inch unibody macbook (with the intergrated graphics) and it is fine for some light gaming. As I said, I can play The Orange Box on it fine

Answer (score 0):

Dell XPS comes with the geforce 9500M GS which is a decent mobile graphics accelerator.

Comment: And you can get it tricked out for 1300 or so.